# What is someone talking about when they indicate a company is involved in assembling and sequencing of automobile wheels?

Tags: automotive-engineering

I'm not an engineer, but I'm doing some consulting work for a company that does this.  While I don't need to know the specifics of what they do for what I am doing, I'd like to be able to talk about it without sounding completely clueless.  My google searches haven't provided much insight.

Comment: Can we assume it's the "sequencing" part that confuses you rather than the "assembling" part?

Comment: A wild guess - the "sequencing" is something to do with setting up the production schedule for the factory making different types of products, not one of the processes that actual make a wheel.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it was just the combination of terms there.  It was something I'd never heard of respecting cars, but if it is process related, that may be why.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not that common to talk about 'assembling' something like automotive wheels as they are usually cast, pressed or machined and as such tend to have relatively few parts and 'sequencing' could mean all sorts of things from the order of manufacturing operations to broader production scheduling. There is certainly no well defined general engineering which is obvious from the context.

To be honest your best course is to just ask them to explain exactly what they do. If you are consulting about something other than the manufacturing and engineering side of the business then this would be an entirely normal thing to ask.

Comment: Yeah, I ultimately will...I just like being able to do some research beforehand, and hate entering an engagement entirely clueless.  Thanks for your input!  Much appreciated!

Comment: I agree with your second statement about just asking, but not your first. many automobile wheels are steel, assembled (welded) from 2-3 separate pieces.